# Wondering if there is a better way in looping over a list of dictionaries and comparing the keys to another dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is a list of dictionaries.

```
segments2 = [
                          {
                            "endTime": "01:09:02;00",
                            "duration": "00:09:02:00",
                            "startTime": "00:59:59;29",
            
                          },
                          {
                            "endTime": "01:13:01:10",
                            "duration": "00:05:20:00",
                            "startTime": "01:09:17;05",
                
                          },
                          { #-> Segment 4
                            "endTime": "01:21:33;21",   #-> 01:15:20:19
                            "duration": "00:06:42:00",  #-> Segment 5 ST -> End time of Segment 3 + 1 Frame -> 01:15:20:20 (HH:MM:SS:FF)
                            "startTime": "01:14:51;22", #-> Segment 5 End 
            
                          },
                        
                        ]
```

Here is one dictionary I am comparing each segment dictionary to.

```
   change_time = {
            "startTime" : "01:15:20:19",
            "duration":"00:00:05:00",
            "endTime" :  "01:15:25:19"
        }
```

Curious to know if there is a better way of comparing each `segment` dictionary from the `segments2` list to this dictionary `change_time`.  I dont think this is the most efficient method.

```
for index,segment in enumerate(segments):
     for segment_key, segment_value in segment.items():
         for change_time_key,change_time_value in change_time.items():
            if index < total_segments-1:
                    if segment_key == 'startTime' and change_time_key == 'startTime' and segment_value == change_time_value:
                        segment_time_code = segment['duration']
```

Comment: there is no comparison in the code you posted, just iterations. Can you also post the comparison part?

Comment: use lambda function

Comment: Is it only the `segments` being compared to `change_time` and is `change_time` only that one dictionary? And then for the `segments` are the around that small size of a few dictionaries or can they grow much larger?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you mean by "comparison" further optimization may or may not be possible. Statement "this is not the most efficient" may be false, at least in the terms of complexity. But if for example you want to match `segment_key` with `change_time_key` then at least one loop (the middle one) can be eliminated.

Comment: @freakish do you mean this line can be removed? 
            for segment_key, segment_value in segment.items():

Answer (score 1):

Dicts in Python allow you to use `==` with them. I added the `change_time` to the end of the `segments2` and run this code:

`[change_time == d for d in segments2]`

It returns:

`[False, False, False, True]`

If you want to check only one field, you can specify it:

`[change_time['startTime'] == d['startTime'] for d in segments2]`

Then you can get all indices of equal dicts. Or you can just run this command:

`change_time in segments2`

which returns `True` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I do want to compare a certain key, for example comparing the values from startTime, not all of the keys.

Comment: Then you can just use `[change_time['startTime'] == d['startTime'] for d in segments2]`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your loop  can be simplified to

```
for segment in segments[:total_segments-1]:
    if segment['startTime'] == change_time['startTime']:
        segment_time_code = segment['duration']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform several lookups, you can create a dict `startTime -> list of segments`:

```
>>> d= {}
>>> for s in segments2:
...     d.setdefault(s["startTime"], []).append(s)
>>> d
{'00:59:59;29': [{'endTime': '01:09:02;00', 'duration': '00:09:02:00', 'startTime': '00:59:59;29'}], '01:09:17;05': [{'endTime': '01:13:01:10', 'duration': '00:05:20:00', 'startTime': '01:09:17;05'}], '01:14:51;22': [{'endTime': '01:21:33;21', 'duration': '00:06:42:00', 'startTime': '01:14:51;22'}]}
```

And then use the dict to find all the segments starting at a given time:

```
>>> d[change_time["startTime"]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyError: '01:15:20:19'
>>> d['01:09:17;05']
[{'endTime': '01:13:01:10', 'duration': '00:05:20:00', 'startTime': '01:09:17;05'}]
```

If you want to compare times (greater or lower), you can sort the `segments2` list and use `bisect`:

```
>>> segments3 = sorted(segments2, key=lambda s: s.get("startTime"))
>>> segments3
[{'endTime': '01:09:02;00', 'duration': '00:09:02:00', 'startTime': '00:59:59;29'}, {'endTime': '01:13:01:10', 'duration': '00:05:20:00', 'startTime': '01:09:17;05'}, {'endTime': '01:21:33;21', 'duration': '00:06:42:00', 'startTime': '01:14:51;22'}]
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_left([s["startTime"] for s in segments3], '01:10:13;07')
2
```

The key is between segments `1` and `2`

```
>>> segments3[1]
{'endTime': '01:13:01:10', 'duration': '00:05:20:00', 'startTime': '01:09:17;05'}
>>> segments3[2]
{'endTime': '01:21:33;21', 'duration': '00:06:42:00', 'startTime': '01:14:51;22'}
```